# Problem resolving javax.servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath

Eclipse can't resolve javax.servlet. I use Apache Tomcat.
My CLASSPATH variable looks as following:

```
 C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib;C:\glassfish3\jdk\lib;
 C:\Programme\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0.5\liferay-portal-6.0.5\tomcat-6.0.26\lib
```

As far as I know `javax.servlet` is in the file servlet-api.jar which is there.
Do I need to configure anything else than the classpath?

Comment: Have you added servlet-api.jar file to the project classpath in Eclipse?

Comment: @Suresh you shouldn't give away your answers for free! :)  adding `servlet-api.jar` is what will fix this problem.

Comment: Adding a loose servletcontainer-specific JAR to runtime classpath isn't the right approach. It will break portability (i.e. your webapp won't be able to run on other servletcontainer makes/versions than the one where the JAR originates). I'll add an answer with the correct approach for Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you're using Eclipse for Java **EE** developers. If ensured, then first integrate Tomcat in your Eclipse environment if not done yet. Open the *Servers* view at the bottom, rightclick it, choose *New*, add *Apache Tomcat* from the list and follow the wizard.

Then rightclick your dynamic web project, choose *Properties* and then go to *Targeted Runtimes* and select the integrated Tomcat from the list and click *OK*.

That should be it.